# Using RxJS ForkJoin to combine results from multiple API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use RxJS forkJoin to combine 2 api calls (and ideally I'd add more to this in time). I'm using RxJs 6.

I have two interfaces. One interface `IMyWrapperObj`, holds an array of the other interface `IData`.

```
export interface IMyWrapperObj {
  status: {
    id: number;
    prop: string;
    anotherProp: string;
  }
 data: Data[]
}

export interface IData {
   prop1: string;
   prop 2: string;
}
```

I have a service which calls a third party api. The way this API is set up, I need to call it twice with different parameters, and combine the results on the Angular side.

```
getSomeDataFromAPI(param1, param2): Observable<IMyWrapperObj> {/// some code here}
```

Now, in the component, I've injected the service into the constructor and in the ngOnInit, I intend to use forkJoin to make 2 api calls and combine the output into a single result.

Here is that code:

```
forkJoin({
   request1: this.dataService.getSomeDataFromAPI('Astronomy', this.query.term),
   request2: this.dataService.getSomeDataFromAPI('History', this.query.term)
}).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The error I'm unable to resolve (on compile) is:

Observable is not assignable to type ObservableInput. Object literally my only specify known properties.

Any thoughts on this? I haven't been able to digest a clear answer.

Comment: Which version of RxJS you're using? Older version did not support dictionary syntax like you have here. I think before version 6.5 this syntax is not supported

Comment: Also what do you have in your service?

Comment: is `getSomeDataFromAPI` returning a type whose properties are not all defined? Can you show your `getSomeDataFromAPI` call?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for forkJoin

I think there is an error with the way of subscribe to fork join

> ```
> forkJoin({
>    request1: this.dataService.getSomeDataFromAPI('Astronomy', this.query.term),
>    request2: this.dataService.getSomeDataFromAPI('History', this.query.term)
> }).subscribe(({request1,request2}) => {
> console.log(request1);
> console.log(request2);
> });
> ```

The usual way I use forkjoin is using array and its indexes

**service.ts:-**

```
   getSomeDataFromAPI(Requests:Array<any>): Any {
    //create a request observable batch array
    let observableBatch = [];
    //inside the array push each http request observable
    Requests.forEach((request)=>{
    observableBatch.push(         
                    //service call
                    this._http
                    .post<IMyWrapperObj>(Url, { 
            requestbodyParam1: request.param1,
            requestbodyParam2: request.param2
                })
                    .pipe(
                        //catcherror block http
                    )
    
                ); //push end
    
         });
   //use forkJoin 
 return forkJoin(observableBatch);

    }
```

**component.ts:-**

//rewrite below code using foreach or map or any way or use interface wrapper as needed

```
    let requests:Array<any>=[{'Astronomy', this.query.term},{'History', this.query.term}];
    


this.dataService.getSomeDataFromAPI(requests:Array)
                .susbcribe((response:Any[])=>{
     console.log(response[0]);//astronomy response
     console.log(response[1]); //history response
         
                 },{error}=>{
                 //error block
               });
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin